# How can I use gcc's automatic dependency generation while being able to move source files?

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

Consider a simple project that has sources in two different directories: `src` for hand-written code and `gen` for generated code.

> Makefile:
>
> ```
> foo: foo.o main.o
>   gcc $^ -o $@
>
> COMPILE = gcc -MD -MP -MF $(@:.o=.d) -Isrc -Igen -c $< -o $@
>
> %.o: src/%.c
>   $(COMPILE)
> %.o: gen/%.c
>   $(COMPILE)
>
> -include $(wildcard *.d)
> ```

> src/main.c
>
> ```
> #include "foo.h"
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main() {
>   printf("%d\n", foo());
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

> src/foo.h
>
> ```
> int foo(void);
> ```

> src/foo.c
>
> ```
> #include "foo.h"
>
> int foo() {
>   return 42;
> }
> ```

This works great, including the dependency tracking:

> ```
> $ make
> gcc -MD -MP -MF foo.d -Isrc -Igen -c src/foo.c -o foo.o
> gcc -MD -MP -MF main.d -Isrc -Igen -c src/main.c -o main.o
> gcc foo.o main.o -o foo
> $ touch src/foo.h
> $ make
> gcc -MD -MP -MF foo.d -Isrc -Igen -c src/foo.c -o foo.o
> gcc -MD -MP -MF main.d -Isrc -Igen -c src/main.c -o main.o
> gcc foo.o main.o -o foo
> ```

`-MP` even lets me move a header to `gen/` without breaking the build:

> ```
> $ mv src/foo.h gen/
> $ make
> gcc -MD -MP -MF foo.d -Isrc -Igen -c src/foo.c -o foo.o
> gcc -MD -MP -MF main.d -Isrc -Igen -c src/main.c -o main.o
> gcc foo.o main.o -o foo
> ```

But unfortunately, I can't move non-headers without everything breaking:

> ```
> $ mv src/foo.c gen/
> $ make
> make: *** No rule to make target 'src/foo.c', needed by 'foo.o'.  Stop.
> ```

That's because the GCC-generated dependency rules look like this:

> ```
> $ cat foo.d
> foo.o: src/foo.c /usr/include/stdc-predef.h gen/foo.h
>
> /usr/include/stdc-predef.h:
>
> gen/foo.h:
> ```

The `foo.o: src/foo.c` dependency prevents `make` from using `gen/foo.c` after I've moved it.  If it weren't there, everything would work:

> ```
> $ sed -i 's|src/foo.c ||' foo.d
> $ make
> make: 'foo' is up to date.
> ```

Is there a way to get this to work automatically, either with different GCC flags or by changing the Makefile somehow?

Comment: I can think of two options: first, every time you move a file, delete the .d file.  Gcc will regenerate an updated one next time its run.   Otherwise create the .d files in a directory structure similar to the source..  (thus `deps/src/foo.d` would represent `src/foo.c` for example).   This way if you move a file, it will not have a .d and rebuild it (note that you still might want to delete the old .d...)

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Deleting the `.d` file would be unfortunate as I'd lose track of the dependency on `foo.h`.  I'm looking for a way to handle moves like this automatically, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are using dependencies in an unusual way (I don't want to say *wrong* ;) ). The first time through your compile works from the pattern rules only, as the dependency file is not yet present. After that you are desynchronized as you are moving files around and after that invoke a build with the old dependency file which carries the wrong path info. Make wasn't designed to run without proper and rigid target information as that would lead to completely uncontrolled builds - why not compile the file anotherproject/notyourbusiness/foo.c if the name fits somehow? (*)

So, if you want to do this, you are rightfully forced to program it explicitly as any implicit functionality would render make completely useless. You could use VPATH (set it to the directories where your sources may appear and remove the path info from the prerquisites in the dependency files) to locate your sources but note that even this one wasn't added for the purpose of catching elusive project scopes.

All in all I would dare to say that if the location of your source files poses such a big hassle during the whole project, you are in for rough times - that is not say that a flexible makefile which allows such configuration changes would be a bad thing, just don't install such behaviour as "normal" build steps.

(*) Of course dependency generation is allowed to lag one cycle behind, but that is not the same as moving the *targets* around in an uncontrolled manner.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at with the "anotherproject/notyourbusiness/foo.c" example... there are exactly two pattern rules, for `src/%.c` and `gen/%.c`, which is far from being "completely uncontrolled"

Comment: Make has no notion of something like a subdirectory as a special _place_ in the filesystem with "natural" borders. `src/%.c` is just a pattern as far as make is concerned, and if presented to the filesystem yields a list of names in that filesystem. Now you are saying that a string X (src/foo.c) should map to a string Y (gen/foo.c), which as far as make is concerned, is completely different as soon as one character is different. Why should it and what would be a sensible default behaviour for this situation? As I said, use VPATH, but be aware that it wasn't introduced to hit moving targets.

Comment: I don't really want make to magically map any strings... mainly I want gcc to stop generating the explicit `foo.o: src/foo.c` dependency and rely on my existing Makefile for that.

Comment: But thanks for the VPATH suggestion!  I didn't even think of that but it may work.

Comment: `sed`-ing away the path in the `.d` file after the compile should work.